Need clarification on Fredholm alternative
Let $A$ be an m by n matrix with, say, real cofficients. Then we have a linear transformation:
$A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$
It follows from (Gilbert Strangs) fundamental theorem of linear algebra that:
$\mathbb{R}^m = Col(A) \oplus L.Null(A)$
where $Col(A)$ is the column space of $A$ and $L.Null(A)$ is the left null space. Furthermore, these summands are orthogonal to eachother.
The left nullspace of $A$ consists of all the vectors $y$ such that $A^Ty=0$
Now, the Fredholm alternative says that either $Ax=b$ has a solution or that there exists a $y$ such that $yA=0$ and $yb \neq 0$.
I feel like from our decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^m$ into orthogonal summands this is painfully obvious and that we could even find an explicit $y$ ($y = b^T$) rather than just a statement about existence.

For example:
Say that there is no $x$ such that $Ax=b$. Then $b$ is not in the column space of $A$, and so must be in the left nullspace of $A$.
Thus $A^Tb=0$
Or, taking the transpose of both sides of this equation:
$b^TA=0$.
Furthermore, if $b \neq 0$ then clearly $b^Tb \neq 0$.

So, I propose the following PhysicsIsHard Alternative
Either $Ax=b$ has a solution, or $b^TA = 0$.
Clearly, my new innovative alternative is far superior to this so called "Fredholm Alternative"
But really, is there something I'm missing here? Perhaps the Fredholm Alternative is a statement that can be made for much more general fields or something?

Note that the Fredholm alternative is usually applied to Fredholm operators between Banach spaces. In the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces, the statement would indeed be trivial.

Please do not repost question. And a large part of your question has been answered in lily’s and user8675309’s comments under your old question.
